# How can I fix importing modules CORS policy error in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, import, module, es6-modules

I searched it on the internet, but I couldn't find a way to fix this error. Why can't I import functions from another file? I tried putting type="module" in the HTML script tag but that's the result I'm getting:

[image]

I'm importing the file like this:

```
import * as StButton from './styleButtons.js';
```

what's wrong? thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like a cross-site access problem. The browser blocks access to local files. 

I'd recommend having your project and all its resources hosted on a localhost server, instead of directly accessing the files.

Comment: Got it, thank you!